# Content of iframe or embed tags doesn't load in iOS

Tags: html, ios, iframe

I created an iframe like this in html:

```
<iframe  id="map-iframe" class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="height:500px; width:100%;" src="map.html" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And also I've tried with embed tag, like this

```
<embed allow-navigation  id="map-iframe" frameborder="0" style="border:0" style="height:500px !important; width:100%;"  class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" src="map.html"></embed>
```

It works perfectly in any browser (e, chrome, safari) with any so (lx, ws, mac), but it's not working in ios (mobile browser like Chrome or safari).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say it's not working, what does that mean? The content doesn't load? It looks weird? etc.

Comment: The content doesn`t load ! ,